# $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^{2}-2 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I know $$ a_{n+1}=a_{n}^{2}-2 $$ has a closed form.

If a_1 is given in complex number and solve this recurrence relation . 
How solve this without using induction.

Comment: How do you avoid induction when you are given an inductively defined sequence?  And what do you mean when you say that the sequence "has closed form" and whether there is "no general solution"?  If the sequence has a closed form, given $a_1$, then doesn't it mean that we have a general solution?

Comment: I’m sorry my English is terrible. I want say is there a just algebraic approach.

Comment: I think the question is understandable, for recursive sequences, "closed form" is understood as finding a general term with respect to $n$ and initial condition. As we have an answer already, I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: In general "we have an answer already" is not particularly germane to whether the Question is clearly stated.  Unclearly stated Questions often get one or more quick Answers.  But in this particular case I do think the Answer's author grasped the idea of "closed form" solution that the OP was looking for, and it should be helpful to the OP in making the problem statement clearer.  I will hold off on voting to close to give the OP a chance to edit accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $a_n=a^{2^n}+a^{-2^n}$.
Then
\begin{align}
a_n^2-2
&=(a^{2^n}+a^{-2^n})^2-2\\
&=a^{2^{n+1}}+a^{-2^{n+1}}\\
&=a_{n+1}
\end{align}
Given $a_1=a^2+a^{-2}$ we get for $|a_1|\geq 2$
$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a_1\pm\sqrt{a_1^2-4}}{2}}$$

Comment: For  the initial value $a_1$ such that $|a_1|<2$, the number $a$ still exists, but it is not real.  However, the formula $a_n=a^{+2^n}+a^{-2^n}$ still works even when $a$ is a complex number.

Comment: Thanks. But i want to know how do you come up with “put a_n=a^2n+a^-2n“ What is this background.?

Comment: While your answer is essentially correct; the first sentence "Put $a_n = a^{2^n}+a^{-2^n}$" is not mathematics; Better start with the argument that this $a$ is indeed independent of $n$.

Comment: Nice. It looks like a very inspired guess that is then verified to solve the equation. Can you suggest a derivation process that would help us understand?